# R, trying to create a column from another one using lag(), grouping() and arrange()

Tags: r, dataframe

I seek guidance from the wise, I'm new to programming.

I'm trying to create a new column in my dataframe with data from another column, by using the functions grouping(), arrange() and lag().
My simplified dataframe looks like this:

| timestamp | id | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 1 | 100 |
| 2023-01-02 | 1 | 102 |
| 2023-01-03 | 1 | 101 |
| 2023-01-04 | 1 | 103 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2 | 10 |
| 2023-01-02 | 2 | 12 |
| 2023-01-03 | 2 | 11 |
| 2023-01-04 | 2 | 13 |

and I want to compute the percent price change compared to 2 days ago for each ID, it would look like this:

| timestamp | id | price | price_%change_2d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 1 | 100 | *N/A* |
| 2023-01-02 | 1 | 102 | *N/A* |
| 2023-01-03 | 1 | 101 | 0.01 |
| 2023-01-04 | 1 | 103 | 0.0098 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2 | 10 | *N/A* |
| 2023-01-02 | 2 | 12 | *N/A* |
| 2023-01-03 | 2 | 11 | 0.1 |
| 2023-01-04 | 2 | 13 | 0.098 |

Mind you the IDs are not grouped and the timestamps are not ordered properly in reality so I want to order them first.

So far I have come up with this code:

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(timestamp) %>%
  df$"price_%change_2d" <- (df$price - lag(df$price, n = 2L)) / (lag(df$price, n = 2L))
```

and it gives me the error:

```
Error in df %>% group_by(id) %>% arrange(timestamp) %>% df$price_%change_2d <- (df$price -  : 
  could not find function "%>%<-"
```

When I try each part of the code independently they work fine, i.e.:

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(timestamp)
```

and

```
df$"price_%change_2d" <- (df$price - lag(df$price, n = 2L)) / (lag(df$price, n = 2L))
```

but I need to order the dataframe before computing the price change.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use `mutate` to use `group_by` like you want.

I.e.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(timestamp) %>%
  mutate(price_perc_change_2d = (price - lag(price, n = 2L)) / (lag(price, n = 2L))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Or from `dplyr 1.1.0` (possibly) shortened to:

```
df %>%
  mutate(price_perc_change_2d = (price - lag(price, n = 2L)) / (lag(price, n = 2L)), .by = "id")
```

Output:

```
  timestamp     id price price_perc_change_2d
  <date>     <dbl> <dbl>                <dbl>
1 2023-01-01     1   100             NA      
2 2023-01-02     1   102             NA      
3 2023-01-03     1   101              0.01   
4 2023-01-04     1   103              0.00980
5 2023-01-01     2    10             NA      
6 2023-01-02     2    12             NA      
7 2023-01-03     2    11              0.1    
8 2023-01-04     2    13              0.0833
```

Comment: Amazing, tyvm! I used mutate for something else right before but I didn't know how to use it here.